# Appending variable to list based on if condition python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a array

```
arr=['a','b','c']
```

and a variable

```
var='a'
```

I am trying to remove the variable from array and append the resultant array to a new array.

```
newarray = []

if var in arr:
    newarray.append(arr.remove(var))
    print(newarray)
```

This does not print anything.  However when I run only `arr.remove(var)` it works...I am not able to append the resultant smaller array to a new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, this is what you may be looking for:

```
arr = ['a','b','c']
var = 'a'
newarray = []
if var in arr:
    arr.remove(var)
    newarray.append(arr)
    print(newarray)
```

Output:

```
[['b', 'c']]
```

Note the output of following:

```
if var in arr:
    print(arr.remove(var))
    print(newarray.append(arr))
    print(newarray)
```

Output:

```
None
None
[['b', 'c']]
```

`arr.remove(var)` and `newarray.append(arr)` work on list in place but do not return anything.

Hence `newarray.append(arr.remove(var))` means `newarray.append(None)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code got a bit mangled. Here's how to fix it:

```py
arr = ['a','b','c']
var = 'a'
newarray = []

if var in arr:
    newarray.append(var)
    arr.remove(var)
    print(newarray)
```

To understand why your original code printed `[None]`, you first need to understand `array.remove()`.  `array.remove` is a *void function*: it does not return a value, only performs tasks.  If you try to get or call its return value in a function such as `array.append()`, Python doesn't know how to react and returns `None`.  The `None` value was then appended to the array properly by the `array.append()` function.

Comment: Thank you..I tried your version, however, for some reason, I was not getting the filtered array printed.

Comment: @Apricot Please see the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

use pop() function instead. Change:

```
newarray.append(var)
print(arr.remove(var))
```

to:

```
newarray.append(arr.pop(0))
print(newarr)
```